# Python pandas - construct multivariate pivot table to display count of NaNs and non-NaNs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table, nan

I have a dataset based on different weather stations for several variables (Temperature, Pressure, etc.),

```
stationID | Time | Temperature | Pressure |...
----------+------+-------------+----------+
123       |  1   |     30      |  1010.5  |   
123       |  2   |     31      |  1009.0  |
202       |  1   |     24      |  NaN     |
202       |  2   |     24.3    |  NaN     |
202       |  3   |     NaN     |  1000.3  |
...
```

and I would like to create a pivot table that would show the number of NaNs and non-NaNs per weather station, such that:

```
stationID | nanStatus | Temperature | Pressure |...
----------+-----------+-------------+----------+
123       |  NaN      |      0      |     0    |       
          |  nonNaN   |      2      |     2    |
202       |  NaN      |      1      |     2    |
          |  nonNaN   |      2      |     1    |
...
```

Below I show what I have done so far, which works (in a cumbersome way) for Temperature. But how can I get the same for both variables, as shown above?

```
import pandas as pd
import bumpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'stationID':[123,123,202,202,202], 'Time':[1,2,1,2,3],'Temperature':[30,31,24,24.3,np.nan],'Pressure':[1010.5,1009.0,np.nan,np.nan,1000.3]})

dfnull = df.isnull()
dfnull['stationID'] = df['stationID']
dfnull['tempValue'] = df['Temperature']
dfnull.pivot_table(values=["tempValue"], index=["stationID","Temperature"], aggfunc=len,fill_value=0)
```

The output is:

```
----------------------------------
                         tempValue
stationID | Temperature           
123       | False                2
202       | False                2
          | True                 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:** thanks to [@root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38595578/python-pandas-construct-multivariate-pivot-table-to-display-count-of-nans-and/38596301?noredirect=1#comment64580792_38596301):

```
In [16]: df.groupby('stationID')[['Temperature','Pressure']].agg([nans, notnans]).astype(int).stack(level=1)
Out[16]:
                   Temperature  Pressure
stationID
123       nans               0         0
          notnans            2         2
202       nans               1         2
          notnans            2         1
```

**Original answer:**

```
In [12]: %paste
def nans(s):
    return s.isnull().sum()

def notnans(s):
    return s.notnull().sum()
## -- End pasted text --

In [37]: df.groupby('stationID')[['Temperature','Pressure']].agg([nans, notnans]).astype(np.int8)
Out[37]:
          Temperature         Pressure
                 nans notnans     nans notnans
stationID
123                 0       2        0       2
202                 1       2        2       1
```

Comment: You can finish it off with a `.stack(level=1)`

Comment: Awesome, @MaxU and @root ! The `.stack(level=1)` was the icing on the cake! (I just wish there was a way to round the output to the nearest integer. I have tried using `round` and `int`, but they did not work)

Comment: @mmeclimate, the updated answer should give you integers - i don't get what do you want to round?

Comment: @MaxU, thanks for the great solution, by the way! What I mean is the output format, for instance, instead of showing '2.0', it would be easier to read the output as '2'.

Comment: @MaxU, this is great! Thanks for the `astype(np.int8)` edit!

Answer (score 0):

I'll admit this is not the prettiest solution, but it works.  First define two temporary columns `TempNaN` and `PresNaN`:

```
df['TempNaN'] = df['Temperature'].apply(lambda x: 'NaN' if x!=x else 'NonNaN')
df['PresNaN'] = df['Pressure'].apply(lambda x: 'NaN' if x!=x else 'NonNaN')
```

Then define your results DataFrame using a MultiIndex:

```
Results = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(zip(*[sorted(list(df['stationID'].unique())*2),['NaN','NonNaN']*df['stationID'].nunique()])),names=['stationID','NaNStatus']))
```

Store your computations in the results DataFrame:

```
Results['Temperature'] = df.groupby(['stationID','TempNaN'])['Temperature'].apply(lambda x: x.shape[0])
Results['Pressure'] = df.groupby(['stationID','PresNaN'])['Pressure'].apply(lambda x: x.shape[0])
```

And fill the blank values with zero:

```
Results.fillna(value=0,inplace=True)
```

You can loop over the columns if that is easier.  For example:

```
Results = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(zip(*[sorted(list(df['stationID'].unique())*2),['NaN','NonNaN']*df['stationID'].nunique()])),names=['stationID','NaNStatus']))
for col in ['Temperature','Pressure']:
    df[col + 'NaN'] = df[col].apply(lambda x: 'NaN' if x!=x else 'NonNaN')
    Results[col] = df.groupby(['stationID',col + 'NaN'])[col].apply(lambda x: x.shape[0])
    df.drop([col + 'NaN'],axis=1,inplace=True)
Results.fillna(value=0,inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {'stationID':[], 'nanStatus':[], 'Temperature':[], 'Pressure':[]}

for station_id, data in df.groupby(['stationID']):

    temp_nans = data.isnull().Temperature.mean()*data.isnull().Temperature.count()
    pres_nans = data.isnull().Pressure.mean()*data.isnull().Pressure.count()

    d['stationID'].append(station_id)
    d['nanStatus'].append('NaN')
    d['Temperature'].append(temp_nans)
    d['Pressure'].append(pres_nans)

    d['stationID'].append(station_id)
    d['nanStatus'].append('nonNaN')
    d['Temperature'].append(data.isnull().Temperature.count() - temp_nans)
    d['Pressure'].append(data.isnull().Pressure.count() - pres_nans)

df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
print(df2)
```

The result is:

```
   Pressure  Temperature nanStatus  stationID
0       0.0          0.0       NaN        123
1       2.0          2.0    nonNaN        123
2       2.0          1.0       NaN        202
3       1.0          2.0    nonNaN        202
```